# How to expand the subform in MS Access 2010 so I can add more columns?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I now have around 10 columns and MS Access won't let me drag the subform any further so that I can add more columns to the form for input. When I do try to widen the width of the subform, it just drags all the 10 columns with it and won't let me add new ones next to it. And I don't want to add columns below the ones that are already there.

I'm really new to Access, and it's really cool with how it works, but any help in the right direction is appreciated as I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Comment: are you trying to edit the subform on the main form? Try editing the actual sub form and see if you yield better results.

Comment: You can also set the form width in the property sheet in design view.